# Почему не передается изображение в canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Не получается передать image в canvas. Не понимаю в чем проблема. Работает через раз. В Яндекс Браузере все работает хорошо, а вот в Хроме например нет.
Вот код :

```
    <input id="upLoad" type="file">
    <img id="snap" src="" alt="" />
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

var image = document.querySelector('img#snap'),
    canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

$('#upLoad').on('change', function () {

   var file = this.files[0];

   console.log(file);

   var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function () {

        image.src = event.target.result;

       canvas.width = image.width;
       canvas.height = image.height;

       context.drawImage(image,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    };


    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

CodePen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybXRBr

Comment: в хроме все норм